# In my angular webapp I get '404 error' when refresh

Tags: angular, http, http-status-code-404, refresh, angular2-routing

I have a two page web service with a Main page and a details page. When I double click on the main page data, I'm able to direct to the details page with the details populated. However, I always get 'Error 404: Not found' when I press 'F5' to refresh the page. I've tried using  'useHash: true' but still no luck.  Can anyone please advise?

my app-routing.module.ts is below;

```js
const routes: Routes = [
  {path: '', redirectTo: '/dashboard', pathMatch: 'full'},
  {path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent},
  {path: 'dashboard/detail', component: DetailComponent},

];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {  useHash: true, enableTracing: true })],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {
}
```

My Main page double click function to direct to the detail page :

```js
  onRowDoubleClick(event) {
    this.routerService.navigate(["dashboard/detail"]);
  }
```

After I get to the details page, if I do refresh from 'F5' or from the URL, I get the error below;

[ERROR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/seGSO.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you have a virtual directory and hosting in IIS, try removing "/" from base href.

```
 <base href="">
```

Comment: glad to know. Please mark it as answer if it worked :)

Answer (score 0):

Add this to the providers array in NgModule

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
],
  providers: [
    {provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy}, //add this
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent] 
})
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for the reply, i tried that either, no luck. My app.module.ts

Comment: @NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    DashboardComponent,
     DetailComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
…  ],
  schemas:[],
  providers: [{provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: PathLocationStrategy}],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
}

Comment: Sorry my bad it will be `HashLocationStrategy` updated the answer

Comment: no luck, still error : HTTP ERROR 404

Problem accessing /. Reason:

    Not Found

Comment: what is your base href in index .html is it set to `'/'`

Comment: I do have that in my index.html, please see below <html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Web</title>
  <base href="/">

</head>
<body>
  <my-app></my-app>
</body>
</html>

Comment: is anyone found solutions? I am getting same issue when i do refresh.. it goes to error route and come back to original route